# wordpress apply filters and is singular()

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'd like to know whether anybody has heard of , or created a workaround to the following problem:

let's say there is a plugin which has code like this,

```
add_filter('the_content'.'some_func');
some_func($content)
{
    if(is_singular())
    {
    //do something and return the content
    }
    else
    {
    //just return the content,dont modify it in any way.
    }
}
```

now in my plugin there is code like this

```
    $doggy = apply_filters('the_content',$content)
```

but because the author of the earlier plugin has specified the is_singular, my $doggy WILL NOT get the content with the changes that the earlier plugin would have applied otherwise.
As a result i wont be able to use the actual final content to do whatever i want in my plugin.

Any help is appreciated, since i just read an article where the author says, "the is singular has been designed so that the filters apply only within the main WP query." So i have an additional question - as to whether there is any way to intercept this. 
I would like to use this apply filters action inside my code like this,

```
wp_insert_post_data($data,$postarr)
{
$data["post_content"] = apply_filters('the_content',$data["post_content"])
$data["post_content"] = my_func($data["post_content"]);
return $data;
}
```

and manipulate the story content, after applying all the filters that would be eventually applied to the content, and then returning the data.

I hope i have explained things clearly.
I need a workaround, since i dont think an official solution exists.
AND-- doing what i need to do ---using--- save post or publish post is NOT AN OPTION FOR MY PURPOSE. Also i cannot do this on the_content filter.
I NEED A SOLUTION THAT WORKS BEFORE THE POST DATA IS INSERTED INTO THE DATABASE.
SO please do not suggest that.

Best Regards,
app_maniac.

Comment: it's not clear why you'd want to do this, filters on the_content are not supposed to be used on data being inserted into the database, it's only for output to the page

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how i could do what i want to do? it would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the filter

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'some_func');
```

and add it again with your customized version of `some_func()` called `some_func_mod()`:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'some_func_mod');
```

Comment: hello birgire,could you please elaborate a bit?? i dont quite understand how this will help me get the modified content( by the other plugin)

Comment: the idea is to use your own function instead of some_func(), so you can overwrite it that way ;-)